# how to pass local streambuf with istream using shared pointer in c++

Tags: c++

I want to pass local [streambuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/) in a std::istream variable of a class and 
return this class and get that istream with the streambuf.

```
 class StreamDataModel {
    public:
    std::shared_ptr<std::istream> istream_ptr;
    void setStreamPointer() {   
        std::string str = "Hello world";
        std::istringstream strstream(str);
        istream_ptr = std::make_shared<std::istream>(strstream.rdbuf());

        return;
    }
    std::shared_ptr<std::istream> getStreamPointer() {
        return istream_ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    StreamDataModel dm;
    dm.setStreamPointer();
    auto ptr = dm.getStreamPointer();
    auto x = ptr;
}
```

the main program cant load the stream buffer since it was local. But i don't want create any extra class member variable for buffer. so is there any way to pass the stream with buffer with shared pointer.